# Shared directory with different password

Tags: windows-xp

Currently whenever somebody try to access the shared directory, I have to provide my user account credentials. Is it popssible in **Windows XP** in some way that whenever somebody wants to access any shared folder, then I provide them with some other user credentials other than windows account credentials ?

Comment: Make a new user account and give it access to the folder, then give that to anyone that wants access. Or if they have an account on the same network, grant them access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest 2 solutions for you:

1. Disable password-protected sharing following [this guidance](http://www.ehow.com/how_6973211_turn-password-protected-sharing-xp.html)
2. Use a FTP server software or Samba server software, so you can use other credentials other than windows account credentials.